# Navigating to Child Components with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have an app built with Vue.js. In this app, I'm using the Vue Router. I successfully have top-level routes working. However, I'm unable to get child routes to work. My code seems to ignore any routes defined within the `children` property of a route. I've setup the problem in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vy0hzraf/1/). The relevant code looks like this:

```
const CustomerMenu = { template: '<div><br />please choose: <router-link to="/customers/list">list</router-link>&nbsp;&nbsp;<router-link to="/customers/stats">stats</router-link></div>' }
const CustomerList = { template: '<div>A list of customers here</div>' };
const CustomerStats = { template: '<div>Customer statistics</div>' };
const Suppliers = { template: '<div>Suppliers</div>' }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/customers', component: CustomerMenu, children: [
      { path: 'list', component: CustomerList },
      { path: 'stats', component: CustomerStats }
    ]},
    { path: '/suppliers', component: Suppliers }
  ]
})

new Vue({
    router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {}
});
```

How do I show the content associated with a route defined in the `children` property of a route. In other words, how do I get the "list" or "stats" components to appear when a user selects there respective links?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing `<router-view/>` inside your CustomerMenu component.
http://jsfiddle.net/sn5vu6ek/

**Remember - every component which has `children` routes has to have  to be able to display children components.**

If you just want to have some part of path common between components, you can either create parent with just `<router-view/>` inside, or specify full path for multiple components.

Comment: Interesting. It makes sense now that you explain it. Just different than what I was expecting.